# Windbg Set Conditional Breakpoints that depends on Call Stack

Tags: c++, debugging, windbg

**The problem**: I need to make a script or an expression that that doesn't break if somewhere on callstack is a function with a specific name.

**Specific question**: How can I get functions on callstack to a list of strings ?

**Example**:

```
Module!MyFunctionWithConditionalBreakpoint    
Module!Function1   
Module!Function2    
Module!Function3  


Module!MyFunctionWithConditionalBreakpoint    
Module!Function1   
Module!ClassA:MemberFunction    
Module!Function3
```

I want `Module!MyFunctionWithConditionalBreakpoint` to break only if the call cames from `Module!ClassA:MemberFunction`

**I need this in unmanaged code**. Managed solution is something like

> System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().ToString().Contains("YourMethodName")

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In WinDbg you may set a conditional breakpoint using special $spat function:

```
bp Module!MyFunctionWithConditionalBreakpoint "r $t0 = 0;.foreach (v { k }) { .if ($spat(\"v\", \"*Module!ClassA:MemberFunction*\")) { r $t0 = 1;.break } }; .if($t0 = 0) { gc }"
```

In pseudo-code it will be something like:

```
t0 = 0
foreach (token in k-command result) {
  if (token.contains("Module!ClassA:MemberFunction")) {
    t0 = 1
    break
  }
}
if (t0 == 0) {
  // continue execution
} else {
  // break into the debugger
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not set a breakpoint on entering Module!ClassA:MemberFunction to enable a breakpoint for Module!MyFunctionWithConditionalBreakpoint and upon leaving Module!ClassA:MemberFunction disabling it?

Comment: Could this be automated?