# use one breakpoint's hit count for another breakpoint's condition

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, conditional-breakpoint

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 on C# code.

I would like to only break on a breakpoint if another breakpoint has been hit (and broken upon.)  Is there a way of doing that?

I would imagine as a subproblem it would be nice to get access to the information that the debugger has.

The rationale for this is I'm interested in only breaking on a certain breakpoint given a certain callstack (and at a certain point in the execution of one of those functions in the callstack).  Perhaps I should be using the callstack instead?  Another reason is it would be interesting to have programmatic access to the stuff that the debugger knows about.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Using local variable

The easiest way to create such a conditional breakpoint would be to create a new thread-static variable (or just static if it should be global). Suppose that our code looks as follows:

```cs
class Program
{
#if DEBUG
    [ThreadStatic]
    static int breakVariable = 0;
#endif

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestMethod2();

        TestMethod1();
        TestMethod2();

        TestMethod2();

        TestMethod1();
        TestMethod2();
    }

    static void TestMethod1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test1");
    }

    static void TestMethod2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test2");
    }
}
```

Let's now assume that you set a breakpoint1 on `Console.WriteLine("test1");` and breakpoint2 on `Console.WriteLine("test2");`. You would like to break at the breakpoint2 only when the breakpoint1 was hit 2 times. In this case you would need to set `Hit Count...` property of the breapoint1 to `break when the hit count is equal to 2`. Then in the `When Hit...` property check `Print a message` and in the textbox type: `{breakVariable = 1}`:

[image: when break]

Then set the property `Condition...` of the breakpoint2 to `breakVariable == 1` and check `Is true`:

[image: condition]

If you would like the breakpoint2 to become inactive after being hit you may again use `When Hit...` property setting its `Print a message` value to `{breakVariable=0}`.

### Using macro

This approach is much harder especially if you don't like VBA (like me:) ) but you may be interested as it does not require any changes in the application code. Let's define two macros:

```vb
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports EnvDTE90a
Imports EnvDTE100
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Module Module1

    Public Sub SetMyBreakpoint()
        Dim bps As EnvDTE.Breakpoints
        bps = DTE.Debugger.Breakpoints.Add(File:="C:\MyProject\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs", _
                                           Line:=25)
        Dim bp As EnvDTE80.Breakpoint2
        For Each bp In bps
            bp.Tag = "mytag"
            ' Add this line only if you want the breakpoint to be removed on hit
            ' Although I don't know why - it does not always worked :(
            bp.Macro = "Macros.MyMacros.Module1.RemoveMyBreakpoint"
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Sub RemoveMyBreakpoint()
        Dim bp As EnvDTE.Breakpoint
        For Each bp In DTE.Debugger.Breakpoints
            If (bp.Tag = "mytag") Then
                bp.Delete()
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Now for the breakpoint1 you still want to set the `Hit Count...` property as previously but now in the `When Hit...` property instead of checking `Print a message` check `Run a macro` and select the `SetMyBreakpoint` procedure. It's very important that you provide the full path of the code file in the `Breakpoints.Add` method and the correct line (you may check the API to find other ways to set a breakpoint, like on the function instead a code file). One small caveat here - I observed that the automatic removal of the second breakpoint does not always worked - but maybe it was my Visual Studio.

### Using call stack

You may again use the `Condition` property of the breakpoint - have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791675/windbg-set-conditional-breakpoints-that-depends-on-call-stack/7800435#7800435) to find some details.

Comment: I'm sorry your answer won't receive more upvotes as my questions don't draw enough attention.  You definitely deserve more.  The macro thing is exactly what I was looking for.  Should I accept now or wait to draw more attention? :-P

Comment: Haha thanks:) But no problem with the lack of attention. I'm glad that I helped and I would be thankful if you could accept the answer.